# Collision between stationary and moving vehicle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Will it save car from force of front collision with a fast moving vehicle if I put my car in neutral?
I am assuming force will only set off stationery vehicle into kinetic motion.

Comment: You gotta be kidding.

Comment: @ChesterMiller why

Comment: You seem to be implying that there will be no damage if the car is in neutral.